# Any way to avoid overlapping of 2 images on android?

Tags: android, image, overlap, translate-animation

For an android app, Im doing infinite Translate Animation.

**imageview** starts first and after a delay of 1 second, **imageview2** starts.

```
Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -500, 500);
animation.setDuration(4000);
imageview.startAnimation(animation);
animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

Animation animation2 = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -500, 500);
animation2.setDuration(4000);
imageview2.startAnimation(animation2);
imageview2.setStartOffset(1000);
animation2.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
```

The problem is that, after sometime **imageview** overlaps **imageview2**.
What Can I do to avoid the overlapping of 2 images ?

Any pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like this:

```
private boolean isViewOverlapping(View firstView, View secondView) {
    int[] firstPosition = new int[2];
    int[] secondPosition = new int[2];

    firstView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    firstView.getLocationOnScreen(firstPosition);
    secondView.getLocationOnScreen(secondPosition);

    int r = firstView.getMeasuredWidth() + firstPosition[0];
    int l = secondPosition[0];
    return r >= l && (r != 0 && l != 0);
}
```

This is a method that will take in two views and check whether they are overlapping. If they are, it will return a boolean of true. I would presume that once you get this boolean returned as true, you would then want to carry out another action to ensure they are not overlapped anymore, such as moving one view down 400 pixels. This would then result in the images not overlapping and you would have avoided the worrying situation. Hope this helps!